# How is the Plain TeX macro "\prod" defined?

Tags: tex-core, math-operators, plain-tex

The macro `\prod` in Plain TeX (probably also in LaTeX) behaves
in distinct ways depending on whether it is used in display or
text style.  In display style super- and sub-scripts are placed
above and below a big Greek letter pi (probably using the keyword
`\limits`), while in text style, subscripts go in the usual place
and the character size is not so big.  I am trying to write a Plain TeX
macro with these characteristics, but I am having trouble with
it.  My best bet is below, together with an attempt to use it,
but it does not work:

```
\def \myprod {\mathchoice {\mathop {\mathchar "1359}\limits }
{\mathop {\mathchar "1351}} {NA} {NA}}

My macro in display style prints ${\displaystyle \myprod _{i=1}^n x_n}$, 
but it should print $\displaystyle \prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts 
are completely off.

My macro in text style prints $\myprod _{i=1}^n x_n$, but it should print 
$\prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts are slightly off.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of subscripts that you describe is the default for a mathop if you do not use `\limits`

`\prod` is not a macro it is defined as

```
\mathchardef\prod="1351
```

in plain tex, which means that it does not have a macro definition but is a math operator from family 3 and character hex 51

If you use a \mathchardef it will also choose the correct larger character in displaystyle automatically (this is specified in the font metrics)

If you are using a different character that does not have a small/large pair specified in the metrics you can use `\mathchoice` as in the third example below.

[image]

```
\def\myproda{\mathop {\mathchar "1359}}% \prod is 1351 not 1359
\mathchardef\myprodb "1351

\def\myprodc{\mathop{\mathchoice{E}{e}{\scriptstyle e}{\scriptscriptstyle e}}}

My macro in display style prints ${\displaystyle \myproda _{i=1}^n x_n}$, 
but it should print $\displaystyle \prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts 
are completely off.

My macro in text style prints $\myproda _{i=1}^n x_n$, but it should print 
$\prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts are slightly off.

\hrule


My macro in display style prints ${\displaystyle \myprodb _{i=1}^n x_n}$, 
but it should print $\displaystyle \prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts 
are completely off.

My macro in text style prints $\myprodb _{i=1}^n x_n$, but it should print 
$\prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts are slightly off.

\hrule


My macro in display style prints ${\displaystyle \myprodc _{i=1}^n x_n}$, 
but it should print $\displaystyle \prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts 
are completely off.

My macro in text style prints $\myprodc _{i=1}^n x_n$, but it should print 
$\prod _{i=1}^n x_n$. Super/subscripts are slightly off.


\bye
```

Comment: Thanks very much @David.   Your \myprodc is precisely what I was looking for.  Now I see that one should use \mathchoice only to choose the character and not the whole macro.

Comment: @Ruy well it depends actually, sometimes it's better to pull the subscripts in to the mathchoice (so they can use letter specific kerning) but then it's harder to use the `_` and `^` syntax, and here it doesn't seem needed, certainly not for the display case with limits setting